# What build environment differences are causing the mesa GBM library to behave differently

Tags: build, compilation, linker, shared-libraries, mesa

I am working on a basic demo application ([kmscube](https://git.ti.com/glsdk/kmscube/trees/master)) to do rendering via the DRM and GBM APIs. My application uses the TI variation of libgbm (mesa generic buffer management). TI provides the [source](http://git.ti.com/glsdk/libgbm/trees/next), [GNU autotools files](http://git.ti.com/glsdk/libgbm/blobs/next/autogen.sh), and a [build environment](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Processor_SDK_Building_The_SDK) (Yocto) to compile it. I compiled GBM in their environment and it works perfectly.

I did not want to use Yocto, so I moved the source into my own build system (buildroot) and compiled it. Everything compiles correctly (using the same autotools files), but when it runs, I get a segmentation fault when I call `gbm_surface_create`. I debugged as far as I could and found that the program steps into the gbm library but fails on `return gbm->surface_create(gbm, width, height, format, flags);`

What would cause a library to run differently when compiled in different environments. Are there some really important compiler or linker flags that I could be missing?

This is the code from the graphics application (in [kmscube.c](https://git.ti.com/glsdk/kmscube/blobs/master/kmscube.c))

```
gbm.dev = gbm_create_device(drm.fd);

gbm.surface = gbm_surface_create(gbm.dev,
                                  drm.mode[DISP_ID]->hdisplay, drm.mode[DISP_ID]->vdisplay,
                                  drm_fmt_to_gbm_fmt(drm.format[DISP_ID]),
                                  GBM_BO_USE_SCANOUT | GBM_BO_USE_RENDERING);
if (!gbm.surface) {
   printf("failed to create gbm surface\n");
   return -1;
}

return 0;
```

This is the call stack that creates the device ( in [gbm.c](http://git.ti.com/glsdk/libgbm/blobs/next/gbm.c))

```
GBM_EXPORT struct gbm_device *
gbm_create_device(int fd)
{
   struct gbm_device *gbm = NULL;
   struct stat buf;

   if (fd < 0 || fstat(fd, &buf) < 0 || !S_ISCHR(buf.st_mode)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "gbm_create_device: invalid fd: %d\n", fd);
      return NULL;  
   }

   if (device_num == 0)
      memset(devices, 0, sizeof devices);

   gbm = _gbm_create_device(fd);
   if (gbm == NULL)
      return NULL;

   gbm->dummy = gbm_create_device;
   gbm->stat = buf;
   gbm->refcount = 1;

   if (device_num < ARRAY_SIZE(devices)-1)
      devices[device_num++] = gbm;

   return gbm;
}
```

(continued in [backend.c](http://git.ti.com/glsdk/libgbm/blobs/next/backend.c))

```
struct gbm_device *
_gbm_create_device(int fd)
{
   const struct gbm_backend *backend = NULL;
   struct gbm_device *dev = NULL;
   int i;
   const char *b;

   b = getenv("GBM_BACKEND");
   if (b)
      backend = load_backend(b);

   if (backend)
      dev = backend->create_device(fd);

   for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(backends) && dev == NULL; ++i) {
      backend = load_backend(backends[i]);
      if (backend == NULL)
         continue;
      fprintf(stderr, "found valid GBM backend : %s\n", backends[i]);
      dev = backend->create_device(fd);
   }

   return dev;
}

static const void *
load_backend(const char *name)
{
   char path[PATH_MAX];
   void *module;
   const char *entrypoint = "gbm_backend";

   if (name[0] != '/')
      snprintf(path, sizeof path, MODULEDIR "/%s", name);
   else
      snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s", name);

   module = dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
   if (!module) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to load module: %s\n", dlerror());
      return NULL;
   }
   else {
      fprintf(stderr, "loaded module : %s\n", name);
   }

   return dlsym(module, entrypoint);
}
```

And here is the code that throws a segmentation fault (in [gbm.c](http://git.ti.com/glsdk/libgbm/blobs/next/gbm.c))

```
GBM_EXPORT struct gbm_surface *
gbm_surface_create(struct gbm_device *gbm,
                   uint32_t width, uint32_t height,
                   uint32_t format, uint32_t flags)
{
   return gbm->surface_create(gbm, width, height, format, flags);
}
```

Comment: Please add your solution as self-answer instead of editing the question

Comment: @FelixSFD I already did but it was deleted as a duplicate